# Python XML Minidom Get element by tag in child node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am curently working on a IRC Bot and want to retrieve the configuration from an XML file that look like this :

```
<server>
  <host> HOST1 </host>
  <port> 6667 </port>
  <channel>
    <name> CHANNAME1</name>
  </channel>
  <channel>
    <name> CHANNAME2 </name>
  </channel>
</server>
<server>
  <host> HOST2 </host>
  <port> 6667 </port>
  <channel>
    <name> CHANNAME3 </name>
  </channel>
</server>
```

And my code look like this :

```
doc = minidom.parse(xml)
node = doc.documentElement
servers = doc.getElementsByTagName("server")

for server in servers:

    channels = server.getElementsByTagName("channel")
    host = server.getElementsByTagName("host")[0].childNodes[0].data
    print host

    for channel in channels:
        NAME = channel.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNode[0].data
        print NAME
```

And the output is

```
HOST1
CHANNAME1
CHANNAME2
CHANNAME3
HOST2
CHANNAME1
CHANNAME2
CHANNAME3
```

But all I need is

```
HOST1
CHANNAME1
CHANNAME2
HOST2
CHANNAME3
```

Is there a way to get all the elements with the tag name "channel" within my node server instead of the whole xml file ?

Comment: `firstChild` is an alias of `childNodes[0]`, for convenience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks correct as is. You have `childNode` when it should be `childNodes` in the `NAME` assignment, but I'm assuming that is just a typo in your question.

Your XML isn't valid though. You need to have some kind of root node wrapping the servers. As it's currently written, I wouldn't expect that to even parse successfully. It should look something like this:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <host> HOST1 </host>
    <port> 6667 </port>
    <channel>
      <name> CHANNAME1</name>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <name> CHANNAME2 </name>
    </channel>
  </server>
  <server>
    <host> HOST2 </host>
    <port> 6667 </port>
    <channel>
      <name> CHANNAME3 </name>
    </channel>
  </server>
</servers>
```

With that XML, and the code you've provided, I get the exact output you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the minidom. Use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead. It can handle subtree searches much better:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse(xmlfile).getroot()

for server in doc.findall('server'):
    host = server.find('./host').text
    print host
    for channel in server.findall('channel'):
        name = channel.find('name').text
        print name
```

Comment: For a question specifically tagged `minidom`, this is frustrating...I'm working on Python 2.3 for backwards compatibility in a legacy system, and ElementTree was part of the 2.5 release. So..."don't use the minidom" isn't even an option.

Comment: @JoshDetwiler: sure it is; you can [install ElementTree into Python 2.3](http://effbot.org/downloads/#elementtree), including the [C extensions, precompiled for Windows](http://effbot.org/downloads/#celementtree).

Comment: @JoshDetwiler: and [lxml](http://lxml.de) supported Python 2.3 up to *at least* version 2.2.x; lxml is a drop-in replacement for ElementTree.

Comment: I appreciate the alternatives, as they probably help someone out there, don't get me wrong. I'm just stuck with the standard library and felt like complaining. Apologies.

Comment: @JoshDetwiler: sure, and I feel for you. The point is that the DOM is a very limited lowest-common-denominator API and a real pain to have to deal with.